# How to display data from two different tables in yii2?

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

I am new to yii2. I have CONDITIONALLY 2 tables: Users (id, address, ...) and Profiles (id, user_id, ...).

I want to get an array of such a plan:

```
  {
        "ID": 2,
        "User_ID": 6,
        "Address":???
},
  {
        "ID": 3,
        "User_ID": 11,
        "Address":??
}
]
```

To do this, I call in the controller Profiles::getProfiles(condition);

```
public static function getProfiles(condition){
   return self::find->where(condition)->all();
```

Now I have an array of ActiveRecords objects, but without an address property. If I add the address property to them, I get an error Setting unknown property: app\models\Profiles::Address

I read about hasMany, hasOne, but I need the address property to be on par with the rest of the profile data.

Please tell me how to do it right

Answer (score 0):

In Profile class:

```
use app\models\User;

//within the body of the Profile class itself
public $address;
public function getUser(){
    return $this->hasOne(User::class,[‘id’=>’User_ID’]);
}
```

Then you can do the following from wherever you want:

```
$result = Profile::find()
    ->joinWith(‘user’)
    ->select([
     ‘profile.id’, // assumes the table name is profile
    ‘user.address’, // assumes the table name is user
    ])
->where([‘profile.id’=>$value])
->all();
```

Comment: it dont work for me. Returned only columns from profiles table. I think its happened,  because model of profiles hasnt property Address. Do you have another ideas?

Comment: If the query did not fail then it must have worked. It would fail completely if it did not find the join. Profiles does not have an address but we have joined profiles to user, which does have the added.

Comment: If you add model `User` as relation to `Profile` you will have to access address as `$profile->user->address`. That's because `ActiveQuery` will populate `Profile` model only with it's own attributes/properties. You would either need to add `public $address` property to `Profile` or use `asArray()` in your query if you want to access it directly.

Answer (score 0):

Don't make it this complicated. it's very easy in yii2, look:

Modify your **Profile Model**:

1 - validation rules:

```
public function rules() {
    return [
        [['user_id'], 'exist', 'targetClass' => User::className(), 'targetAttribute' => ['user_id' => 'id']],
    ];
}
```

2- getUser() :

```
public function getUser() {
    return $this->hasOne(User::className(), ['id' => 'user_id']);
}
```

from now on, every instance of profile model, will have an attribute named `->user` (look at the name of the method: get**User**() ), and it is a active record object of the **User model**.
See, we can access address everywhere just like this:

```
$address = Profile::findOne($id)->user->address;
```